# Is Request.getHeader("host") vulnerable?

Tags: penetration-test, xss, source-code, code-review

If the following is the code snippet, what would be your suggestions?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getHeader("Host")%>/XXX/xxx.js"></script>
```

Is this a clear example of XSS? If yes, what are the attack scenarios which can be used by an attacker?

Comment: Is part of your question: can the value of `request.getHeader("Host")` be faked? Essentially allowing the attacker to make the script source `src="http://attackersdomain/XXX/xxx.js"`?

Comment: @s_hewitt: yes, that should also be the part of the question.

Comment: Host header can result in stored XSS and not in reflective XSS (unless you are trying to XSS yourself). Server processing your request doesn't need to have the same hostname as the host you sent your request to. So you can a request to host a with host header set to host b. But in most scenarios you will only be affecting yourself and not anyone else unless developer have made a mess in the code and there is some persistence of host header which will somehow be used for some other users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a XSS vulnerability, but it's quite difficult to exploit: Take for example the following URL:

`http://anything."><script>xss</script>.example.com/aa/bb`

This URL will carry an XSS payload in Host parameter when navigated to, but:

1. DNS would have to resolve this strange domain to the IP with vulnerable application (so unless the DNS is quite forgiving attacker would require DNS poisoning)
2. The browser would have to skip encoding the hostname - usually the hostname is percent encoded by the browser (so `<script>` becomes `%3Cscript%3E`). You could of course forge the request outside browser.
3. Target server would have to process the request in the context of the vulnerable website, which is not that simple. For example - if this application is installed as a `VirtualHost` in Apache, this `Host` header will not match any `VirtualHost` and will be processed by a fallback or first `VirtualHost`.

It would be much more dangerous if this XSS was stored and not reflected, because then you could skip the (1) DNS and (2) encoding requirements. You could just plant the payload by sending manual HTTP request outside the browser. This payload would be then visible for 'standard' browser-based visitors of the vulnerable site.

So, as a conclusion - this is a XSS vulnerability, but with low exploitation probability. Still, the application should fix it by escaping the Host header being displayed.

Comment: can the value of request.getHeader("Host") be faked? Essentially allowing the attacker to make the script source at src="http://attackersdomain/XXX/xxx.js"?

Comment: @p_upadhyay it could be easily faked outside the browser, but the application would have to accept such request (see point 3 of the answer). In browser - not likely, it would require fiddling with the DNS.